# VirtualBox guest can't ping or RDP other guests, can reach host

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have VirtualBox 4.3 on Debian 8 (brand new install from repository) with a couple of Win 2012 guests running in full GUI mode. I was so excited yesterday when I finally figured out and realised how simple it was to set up networking so that:

- WIN01 can ping WIN02 and vise-versa
- WIN01/02 can ping host and vise versa
- Both guests had Internet access
- I could RDP from one guest to the other

It seemed using Bridged mode and selecting the same host adapter does the trick, before refreshing IP addresses.

I created another Server 2012 VM, this time a Core installation, before retiring for the night. This evening I power up my host and VMs to continue studying and cannot ping/rdp between any of them.

I've been fumbling with this for over an hour, I'm sure I haven't changed the network settings for these VMs (I did try other options though before switching back to Bridged Mode).

Pinging the other guest resolved the correct IP address but no response.
Can ping the host, gateway address/home router, and Google.com.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check firewall?

Comment: Are the bridged to the same adapter? Is the adapter connected to a network? If you switch between wifi and lan, you need to change the bridge, too.

Comment: I haven't checked the firewall because I never had to touch that to begin with, and hadn't made changes to the firewall on any server.

They are both bridged to my wifi card. Both servers can ping the host and my home router, just not each other. They are both on the same subnet.

Comment: I killed my Linux box somehow and instead of fixing that I've switched back to W10 for a little while. I haven't run into the same issue yet, all settings the same